# how to change Sprite size on launch

Tags: flash, sprite

I'm totally new to flash, and I'm trying to build a very simple app.

1. I have one as file in which I defined my class which inherent from Sprite, with the name mySprite.
2. I have a fla which is of the mySprite class, and a size of 400x400(I must assign a size when define the fla).

my question is, when this flash is launched, I want to read some data from outside (width&height) and change the flash windows size to these specified size.

I tried many ways, but can't succeed. Every time the flash is launched, window size is 400x400.

is there any possible way to get that done?

Great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that with flash window, but here two other ways:

a. If you launch your flash app in web-page, then you can use ExternalInterface class to call JavaScript methods and resize flash app size. More info here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cb2.html

b. If you know your app sizes at compilation time, you can add these strings at top of your Main class .as file:

```
    [SWF(width=800, height=600)]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main()
        {
        }
    }
```